# How to show a string variable in flutter which changes when a button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want show a string vaiable which changes it's value when a button is pressed. Inside the body there is variable name `pressedText`. It is a static variable. When a button is pressed I want to show it's updated value, but can not show anything right now. Can I show it's updated value?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            pressedText,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Wrap(
                children: _buildButtonsWithNames(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),      
  }
}
```

Comment: Use setState to update the value in Ui and make sure you are using statefull widget

Comment: This is literally the hello world example provided when you init a project

Comment: Thanks. Problem is I have a list of elevated buttons and do not know how to make it work. I mean when a particular button from that list is pressed do not know how to handle it.

Comment: @masfiqreza Do you want to change the text on the basis of which button is pressed?

Comment: @bharats yes. I have a list of buttons which is generated by user input. Now I want that each time any button from that list is pressed I will concatenate something in string variable. And I will show that updated string. Now this can be done by setState. problem is how to know which button from that list is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change with using setState  and bind your `Wrap` widget with `InkWll` and call `setState` in the onTap function or you can pass a function to your `_buildButtonsWithNames`.

```
Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap:(){
                   setState(() {
                    pressedText = "change Text"
                  });
                 },
                child: Wrap(
                children: _buildButtonsWithNames(),
                ),
              )
            ),
          )
```

Comment: do I need to add onTap() inside any button class?

Comment: In Button class, you don't need but if you pass the callBack function you need to use `onTap` in the button class. And if you use multiple button it would be good to pass with function.